# How do Growing weapons interact with Trip Limitations?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, creature-size, trip

Normally, of course, character A cannot trip character B who is +2 size categories different.

*Would having a growing trip weapon alter this?*
An example to hopefully illustrate this point:

- Char A is Medium, B is Huge
- A activates his Growing Kama, and is now holding a Large Kama
- A uses the Kama to trip B
  (Made possible because there is only one size category difference between A's weapon and B.)

---

(I doubt that this is how this works, but it would be remiss of me to not fully research ways to extend the options of what I can trip.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'm trying to avoid asking a question that would generate a list. I'm fairly familiar with most ways I can achieve this goal, so just sounding out fringe cases.

Comment: No problem. Better I be overreading than you underasking. Or something. `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the relevant sections from the CRB:

> Combat Maneuvers:
>
> > **Trip:** You can attempt to trip your opponent in place of a melee attack.  You can only trip an opponent who is no more than one size category larger than you.
>
> Weapon Size:
>
> > A weapon's size category isn't the same as its size as an object.  Instead, a weapon's size category is keyed to the size of the intended wielder.  In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories smaller than the wielder, a one-handed weapon is an object one size category smaller than the wielder, and a two-handed weapon is an object of the same size category as its wielder.
>
> Special weapon qualities:
>
> > **Trip:** You can use a trip weapon to make trip attacks.  If you are tripped during your own trip attempt, you can drop the weapon to avoid being tripped.

Since the trip Combat Maneuver specifies "larger than *you*" (not "larger than what you're using to trip"), and nothing in the Weapons section (either in the trip weapon quality or under weapon size) overrides this, by RAW your scenario doesn't work.

Comment: Bah! I was expecting as much, as stated, but I was naively hoping for some better news. Thanks much!